# Como resolvo este problema no seasplot?

Tags: r

Fazendo esse código:

```
library(BETS)
library(TStools)
selic <- BETS.get(4189, from = '2000/01/01', 
                   to= '2016/02/01',freq=12)
seasplot(selic,outplot = 3,trend = F)
```

Dá esse resultado

```
Error in if (diff(range(colSums(ynt))) <= .Machine$double.eps^0.5) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Se não tem missing values usando de janeiro a janeiro, dá certo. Como faço para tirar os missing values e rodar?

Comment: De onde vem o pacote `TStools` com maiúsculas? E a função `seasplot`?

Comment: Oi. Vem do Github http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2014/04/19/tstools-for-r/

Comment: Seasplot vem do pacote TStools tbm

Comment: Parece ser um bug na função, Editei a linha onde dá o erro, inclui o `na.rm = TRUE` em `colSums`. Ficou assim: `if (diff(range(colSums(ynt, na.rm = TRUE))) <= .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5){`. É na linha 140 da source.